# jquery does not remove element

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink

I've a page that uses jquery mobile and I've got the following simple problem:

A webpage with a (single) link somewhere in the DOM:

```
<a data-theme="a" data-role="button" href="https://m.mybet.com">
Smartphone-Version nutzen</a>
```

And I added a button like this to the html

```
<input type="button" onclick="javascript:remove_link();"/>
```

My javascript looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function remove_link() {
        console.log("1")
        $("a").remove();
        console.log("2")
    }
</script>
```

However, when clicking the button the chrome browser tells me:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'remove' of null
remove_link 
onclick
```

I also tried empty() instead, same problem. Why?

Comment: Care to create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: is jQuery correcly included in the page? If you type $('a') in the console, what do you get?

Comment: It works here: http://jsfiddle.net/Q7kJd/

Comment: Thanks for the answers. You can simply check it out if you set your chrome to any mobile browser and then go to "https://www.mybet.de" to get the mobile start page. Then you can verify it by typing $('a') into the console. It will return null although the page contains a link...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found out. I use native javacript now:

```
document.querySelector( 'a' ).remove()
```

does the job.

Answer (score 0):

I allways use ids with javascript, is easier for me. Try this:

```
<a data-theme="a" id="id1" data-role="button" href="https://m.mybet.com">
Smartphone-Version nutzen</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function remove_link() {
        console.log("1")
        $("#id1").remove();
        console.log("2")
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a data-theme="a" data-role="button" href="https://m.mybet.com">
Smartphone-Version nutzen</a>

<input id="remove_link" type="button" />

<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#remove_link').click(function() {
    console.log("1")
    $("a").remove();
    console.log("2")
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have not loaded jQuery. Make sure you include the `<script src="path/to/jquery.js"></script>` before calling your function.

Without loading jQuery, your browser is calling the native `$` function.

```
// native jQuery function
function $(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id); // may return null
}
```

The native function may return `null` instead of an empty jQuery object. It is also searching for an id, rather than a css selector. In your case, an element with id 'a' rather than all anchor elements.